# SQL - user related row on group by

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table schemas:

- Comments (**comment_id**, text)
- Votes (**comment_id, user_id**, value)

`Votes.value` can be either `-1` or `1`.

To get all of the comments with their respective score, I do a simple group query:

```
SELECT comments.*, SUM(votes.value) as score
FROM comments
LEFT JOIN votes on comments.comment_id = votes.comment_id
GROUP BY comments.comment_id
```

This request can be performed by any user, and I have a variable for his `user_id`.

How can I also select a column `my_vote` to have the value of the user's vote, or `null` if the user did not vote?

**Note:**

Think about stackoverflow, where each answer is upvoted/downvoted by users, and each user can see if he upvoted or downvoted.

**Edit:**

I found a solution -

```
SUM(IF(user_id = $user_id, value, NULL)) as my_vote
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very elegant solution is to do:
`SUM(IF(user_id = $user_id, value, NULL)) as my_vote`

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following:

```
SELECT c.*, SUM(v.value) as score, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN v.user_id = $user_id THEN value END) as my_vote
FROM comments c LEFT JOIN
     votes v
     on c.comment_id = v.comment_id
GROUP BY c.comment_id;
```

This uses the MySQL shorthand that treats boolean expressions as numbers in a numeric context.

Comment: Although this solution lets me know if the user voted or not, it does not give me the vote itself. I have an edit to the question that solves it using the same idea of comparing user, but giving me the actual value